# How to read from secondary mongo using mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I use mongoengine "connect" method to access mongo db. Now I have replica set configured on mongodb servers.
For performance optimization I want to route all my read request to slave/secondary mongo servers with specific tags.

Here is my connect call

```
mongoengine.connect(attrs['DB_NAME'], conn,
read_preference=ReadPreference.SECONDARY_PREFERRED,
tag_sets=[{'loc': 'nm'}, {}],
replicaSet='replset',
host=attrs['HOST'], port=attrs['PORT'],
username=attrs['USERNAME'], password=attrs['PASSWORD'],
max_pool_size=attrs['MAX_POOL_SIZE'])
```

Error I am getting on execution

> mongoengine.connection.ConnectionError: Cannot connect to database
>   default :
>   172.22.67.38:27017 is not a member of replica set replset

Comment: may your mongo replSet is not correkt configured, try to connect to the mongo shell and type rs.status(). then show us the output please

Comment: Thanks Ark! you are right my mongo server was not tagged with correct replica set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to connect to mongodb using pymongo 2.8 and mongoengine 0.8.7 for secondary read preference.

```
from pymongo.read_preferences import ReadPreference

mongoengine.connect(<db_name>, <db_alias>,
    read_preference=ReadPreference.SECONDARY_PREFERRED,
    tag_sets=[{'loc': 'nm'}, {}],
    replicaSet='replset',
    host='mongodb://<username>:<password>@172.22.67.38:27017/<db_name>', port=attrs['PORT'],
    max_pool_size=100)
```

Comment: How can you overwrite the read preference on the query? I am trying 
`<collection_name>.objects().read_preference(ReadPreference.SECONDARY_PREFERRED)`
However, it does not seem to be working. The query always goes to the primary. Using pymongo 2.7.2 and mongoengine 0.8.7